# Adding Pinterest to telescope:share package

Tags: meteor, telescope

I am looking into telescope right now and got my site up with a bit of custom design ready to go into the wild. The only thing I am missing at the moment is Pinterest in the sharing Module which is Vital for my platform. Can anyone tell me what needs to be done in order to add it to the package without touching the package itself?

Cheers,
Seb

Answer (score 0):

That package is really simple (it's just a list of links), so I think in this case it's safe to clone it and modify it to your needs.